# How to implement a generic RepositoryFactory?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, factory-pattern

I'm trying to implement a Generic Repository. This is what I've got so far ...

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory
{
    IRepository<T> RepositoryOf<T>() where T : class;
}

public class EntityFrameworkRepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public EntityFrameworkRepositoryFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IRepository<T> RepositoryOf<T>() where T : class
    {
        var repository = _container.Resolve<IRepository<T>>();
        return repository;
    }
}
```

The RepositoryFactory is used by my unit of work implementation

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<T> RepositoryOf<T>() where T : class;
    void Commit();
}
```

Anyway, the question I want to ask is whether having the RepositoryFactory implementation depend on IWindsorContainer is correct?

I needed a way of asking for an IRepository of any type, so my installer code does this ...

```
// Windsor Container
container.Register(
    Component.For<IWindsorContainer>()
        .Named("Container")
        .Instance(container)
    );
```

Which just seems to go against the whole concept of IoC, but then maybe the whole idea of asking for a repository does that anyway.

**Edit (As reply to [miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol)'s answer)**

I am already using Windsor to create the repositories for me with the following code in my installer ...

```
// Generic Repository
container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof (IRepository<>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof (EntityFrameworkRepository<>))
        .ServiceOverrides(
            ServiceOverride.ForKey("objectContext").Eq("ObjectContext"))
    );
```

I have used ServiceLocator in the past to achieve what I want, but have read that it's a bit of an anti-pattern. So was trying to avoid using it. Although I have to admit that I'm not sure why, as what I've done also seems wrong as I am bound to using Castle Windsor as my IoC/DI framework. Service Locator is meant to be framework agnostic.

So, I'm a bit confused!

Comment: Added this is a reply, but it's more of a comment -- these might tangentially be useful (answered a similar question earlier today):   [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c
  [2]: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.htm

Comment: Yes there is plenty of similar questions. I think i have answered about 3 of them..

Comment: @Tim: Link #2 is broken.

Comment: Hmm .. will try again :) Thanks Daniel. http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why do you need  `IRepositoryFactory` when you are using an IoC framework. However having dependencies to specific IoC container implementations scattered though the code base is generally not a good idea. Most of the time when I **really can't find a way** to make the container inject dependencies to my objects I use Service Locator Pattern, [here](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) you can find a commonly used implementation for .net. Then your factory method would look like this:

```
public IRepository<T> RepositoryOf<T>() where T : class
{
  return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository<T>>();
}
```

Nevertheless it seems like you could just make Windsor create the generic repository for you anyways:

```
container.Register(
  Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(GenericRepositoryImplementation<>))
);
```

and having them injected to your objects like so:

```
public class ClassThatRequiresSomeRepos
{
  IRepository<OneEntity> repoOne;
  IRepository<TwoEntity> repoTwo;

  public ClassThatRequiresSomeRepos(IRepository<OneEntity> oneEntityRepository, IRepository<TwoEntity> twoEntityRepository)
  {
    _repoOne = oneEntityRepository;
    _repoTwo = twoEntityRepository;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the first thing that jumped into my head when I read this, good answer.

Comment: please see the edit to my question. tbh, I am not sure if ServiceLocator is an anti-pattern or not. It seems fine to me as long as you limit the number of places it's called.