# Is there a way to avoid passing null parameters to class under test when the dependency are not used?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Given the following class and test

```
public class UserService
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepo;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepo)
    {
        _userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public User Get(int id)
    {
        var user = _userRepo.Get(id);
        if(user == null)
            throw new CustomException();

        return user;
    }
}
```

Unit Tests:

```
[Fact]
public void MissingUser_ThrowsException()
{
    // Arrange
    var userService = new UserService(null);

    // Act
    Action result = userService.Get(0);

    // Assert
    result.Throws<CustomException>();
}

[Fact]
public void ExistingUser_ReturnsUser()
{
    // Arrange
    var user = new User()
    {
        Id = 0
    };

    var userRepo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    userRepo
        .Setup(m => m.Get(0))
        .Return(user);

    var userService = new UserService(userRepo.Object);

    // Act
    var result = userService.Get(0);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(user, result);
}
```

Is there a way to avoid passing in null parameters into the constructor when I know the dependencies will not be called in the test? If the class under test now requires a new constructor argument, I'd need to add another null parameter to this test and all other test that don't utilize that dependency.

**Update:**

I'm using `Moq` and `XUnit`. That is, I want to avoid using setup methods as I agree with the philosophy of `XUnit`. However, any mocking framework would still have the same problem.

I added another test that uses the mock. The case that I'm trying to avoid is having to deal with adding additional parameters to the constructor of the class under test when I don't need to.

If I were to add another dependency in the constructor of `UserService` that is used by the `Get` method, I would want only the second test to fail at run time. Currently, I would need to add another parameter to the ctor of `UserService` for both tests.

The more I think about this, the more I realize I want to use a IoC to construct my concrete (class under test). Is using an DI/IoC container in unit tests recommended?

Comment: It sound like you are looking for a [Mock framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use)

Comment: You could just run a setup which is called before each test method if a mocking framework is over kill for your situation

Comment: I updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is odd that you aren't using a mocking framework, it sounds like your question relates to another issue. Many unit test will be written and the constructor for the class under test may change. What you are asking, I think, is how do you avoid the busy work of changing each and every test when you make changes to the constructor signature of the class under test?

One way to avoid this is to use a helper class to manage the construction of your test instances. Here's a simple example:

```
public class UserServcieMockManager
{
    //mock objects here if you're using a mocking framework
    public UserService GetServiceForTesting()
    {
        return new UserService(null); //here's where the mocks would be used
    }
}
```

The reason I've called this class "Mock Manager" is because this is also where you would instantiate your mocks. Then when the constructor signature changes, you only have to change the one method that creates the test instance.

This type of helper class also becomes very useful as a way to centralize the setup logic for mocking scenarios that are reused between tests.

Answer (score 1):

> The more I think about this, the more I realize I want to use a IoC to construct my concrete (class under test). Is using an DI/IoC container in unit tests recommended?.

I prefer creation of `class under test` within `Setup` or `Init` method and see no reason to avoid doing it.

If you want to use IoC/DI to create your `class under test`, you can use AutoMoq ([see on GitHub](https://github.com/darrencauthon/AutoMoq), [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMoq/)).

There is an exmple of usage:

```
[TestClass]
public class ServiceConsumerTestWithAutoMoq
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoA()
    {
        //arrange
        var mocker = new AutoMoqer();
        var sut = mocker.Create<ServiceConsumer>();

        //act
        sut.DoA();

        //assert
        mocker.GetMock<IServiceA>().Verify(it => it.Do(), Times.Once());
        mocker.GetMock<IServiceB>().Verify(it => it.Do(), Times.Never());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DoB()
    {
        //arrange
        var mocker = new AutoMoqer();
        var sut = mocker.Create<ServiceConsumer>();

        //act
        sut.DoB();

        //assert
        mocker.GetMock<IServiceA>().Verify(it => it.Do(), Times.Never());
        mocker.GetMock<IServiceB>().Verify(it => it.Do(), Times.Once());
    }
}

public interface IServiceConsumer
{
    void DoA();
    void DoB();
}

public class ServiceConsumer : IServiceConsumer
{
    public IServiceA serviceA { get; set; }
    public IServiceB serviceB { get; set; }

    public ServiceConsumer(
        IServiceA serviceA,
        IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public void DoA()
    {
        serviceA.Do();
    }

    public void DoB()
    {
        serviceB.Do();
    }
}


public interface IServiceA
{
    void Do();
}

public interface IServiceB
{
    void Do();
}
```

There is another library [Moq.AutoMocker](https://github.com/tkellogg/Moq.AutoMocker) that is developed by member of [Moq Team](https://github.com/Moq?tab=members), [Tim Kellogg](https://github.com/tkellogg).

But I'd rather use `Setup` or `Init` method to create `class under test`.

There is code example that I would use to solve your issue.

```
[TestClass]
public class ServiceConsumerTestWithInit
{
    private Mock<IServiceA> serviceAMock;
    private Mock<IServiceB> serviceBMock;
    private IServiceConsumer sut;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        serviceAMock = new Mock<IServiceA>();
        serviceBMock = new Mock<IServiceB>();
        sut = new ServiceConsumer(
            serviceAMock.Object,
            serviceBMock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DoA()
    {
        //act
        sut.DoA();

        //assert
        serviceAMock.Verify(it => it.Do(), Times.Once());
        serviceBMock.Verify(it => it.Do(), Times.Never());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DoB()
    {
        //act
        sut.DoB();

        //assert
        serviceAMock.Verify(it => it.Do(), Times.Never());
        serviceBMock.Verify(it => it.Do(), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing null, I'd mock `IUserRepository` and simply pass the mocked object.

This way a check against null doesn't throw e.g. an `ArgumentException`... (if you would implement such checks which is pretty handy in DI code).

If you still do not want that, implement another empty ctor for testing. Mark it internal and make the assembly internals visible to your test project. Or protected and have a derived test class.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way you can force the caller to always pass a not null value.

The best you can do is use factory pattern to pass IRepositoryFactory to the constructor so you will only have 1 parameter and will need to check for null for only that parameter.

Your RepositoryFactory will return the types for each repository you will need.

[How to implement a generic RepositoryFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501046/how-to-implement-a-generic-repositoryfactory)

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you are looking for a [Mock framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use).
Personally, I Prefer [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks)

I am not sure I remember the syntax for it, but it is very easy. If I am not mistaking it is something like:

```
 var mockedUserReop = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IUserRepository >();
```

The full method will be:

```
[TestInitialize, SetUp]
public void TestInitilize()
{
    var mockedUserReop = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IUserRepository >();
    UserService = new UserService(mockedUserReop );
}
```